# Copying images to a remote server in a job results in an invalid datalength of 1024 bytes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have images that are stored in a table on remote servers. The table is using the image column data type.

Our replication client (not SQL server replication it's custom) copies the data in the table to a central database using a series of triggers and jobs from the remote locations to a central database. What I've discovered is that the images as copied down using the replication jobs is always 1024 bytes.

I wrote a query to try and figure out why this is happening and this is what I discovered.

If I run the below query in SSMS things come across OK and I can update and repair the image data for records that were copied by the original replication job. However, if I run this same query inside a job, the size of the image column is always 1024 bytes -- the same as what's occurring when the replication job runs.

Anyone know why this might be happening?

Thanks.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

IF object_id('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmp

DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(255) = NULL
    ,@cnt INT = 1

SET @msg = 'Count' + ' | ' + '  DocDate' + ' | ' + 'LocId' + ' | ' + '      TicketId' + ' | ' + 'DocSeq' + ' | ' + 'DataLen'

RAISERROR (
        @msg
        ,10
        ,0
        )
WITH NOWAIT

SET @msg = '----------------------------------------------------------------'

RAISERROR (
        @msg
        ,10
        ,0
        )
WITH NOWAIT

SELECT ptd.LocId
    ,pt.DocTime
    ,ptd.TicketId
    ,ptd.DocSeq
INTO #tmp
FROM TICKET_DOCUMENT (nolock) ptd
INNER JOIN TICKET (nolock) pt
    ON pt.TicketId = ptd.TicketId
        AND convert(DATE, pt.DocTime) BETWEEN '2/1/15' AND '2/14/15'
WHERE DATALENGTH(Data) = 1024

WHILE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM #tmp
        )
BEGIN
    DECLARE @server VARCHAR(20)
        ,@LocId INT
        ,@sql VARCHAR(4000)

    SELECT TOP 1 @LocId = LocId
    FROM #tmp

    SELECT @server = servername
    FROM Location
    WHERE LocId = @LocId

    DECLARE @tmp TABLE (
        TicketId BINARY (6)
        ,DocTime DATETIME
        ,DocSeq INT
        ,Data IMAGE
        )

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#lmt') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #lmt

    SELECT TOP 1 *
    INTO #lmt
    FROM #tmp
    WHERE LocId = @LocId

    SET @sql = 'SELECT rptd.TicketId
    ,t.DocTime
    ,rptd.DocSeq
    ,rptd.Data
FROM ' + @server + '.db_name.dbo.ticket_document rptd
INNER JOIN #lmt t
    ON t.TicketId = rptd.TicketId
        AND t.DocSeq = rptd.DocSeq
        AND t.LocId = rptd.LocId'

    INSERT INTO @tmp
    EXEC (@sql)

    WHILE EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM @tmp
            )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @TicketId BINARY (6)
            ,@DocSeq INT
            ,@DataLen INT
            ,@DocTime DATETIME

        SELECT TOP 1 @TicketId = TicketId
            ,@DocTime = DocTime
            ,@DocSeq = DocSeq
            ,@DataLen = datalength(Data)
        FROM @tmp

        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        UPDATE TICKET_DOCUMENT
        SET Data = t.Data
        FROM TICKET_DOCUMENT ptd
        INNER JOIN @tmp t
            ON t.TicketId = ptd.TicketId
                AND t.DocSeq = ptd.DocSeq
        WHERE t.TicketId = @TicketId
            AND t.DocSeq = @DocSeq

        COMMIT TRANSACTION

        SET @msg = dbo.udf_PadString('left', convert(VARCHAR(6), @cnt), ' ', 5) + ' | ' + convert(VARCHAR, @DocTime, 101) + ' | ' + dbo.udf_PadString('left', convert(VARCHAR(2), @LocId), ' ', 7) + ' | 0x' + convert(VARCHAR, @TicketId, 2) + ' | ' + dbo.udf_PadString('left', convert(VARCHAR(3), @DocSeq), ' ', 6) + ' | ' + dbo.udf_PadString('left', convert(VARCHAR(11), @DataLen), ' ', 7)

        RAISERROR (
                @msg
                ,10
                ,0
                )
        WITH NOWAIT 

        DELETE
        FROM @tmp
        WHERE TicketId = @TicketId
            AND DocSeq = @DocSeq

        SET @cnt += 1
    END

    DELETE #tmp
    FROM #tmp t
    INNER JOIN #lmt l
        ON l.LocId = t.LocId
            AND l.TicketId = t.TicketId
            AND l.DocSeq = t.DocSeq
END
```

Comment: can you try to use temp table #tmp2 instead of @tmp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are seeing difference behavior between SSMS and SQL Agent, that implies a session-level setting is the cause. Try adding the following to the top of that query:

```sql
SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647;
```

---

Notes related to the query itself:

1. End each statement / query with a semi-colon (;)
2. Delcare `#tmp` and do `INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT...`, just like you do for `@tmp`
3. Remove the `(nolock)` hints entirely, or at least add the `WITH` keyword to the left of the hint: `TableName WITH (NOLOCK)`
4. Delcare `#lmt` and do `INSERT INTO #lmt SELECT/EXEC...`, just like you do for `@tmp`
5. Replace both WHILE loops with explicit CURSORs (they are more efficient; also, set-based UPDATE would be even better for the inner WHILE loop, unless you really want the per-item stats)
6. Replace `UPDATE TICKET_DOCUMENT` with `UPDATE ptd`
7. Use `VARBINARY(MAX)` instead of `IMAGE` for datatype of `Data` field in `@tmp`
8. Remove the BEGIN TRAN / COMMIT (they serve no purpose for a single query)
9. Don't specify `VARCHAR` (or `NVARCHAR` or `VARBINARY`) without also specifying a size since the default is not *always* 30: it is sometimes 1, depending on where it is used!!
10. Remove all calls to `udf_PadString` as they are not needed. Instead, use the built-in padding feature of [RAISERROR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) as follows:

    1. Declare the following at the top of the script:

       ```sql
       DECLARE @StringDocTime VARCHAR(30);
       ```
    2. Change `@TicketId` to be `VARBINARY(6)` instead of `BINARY (6)`
    3. Replace your current `SET @msg = dbo.udf_PadString('left',...` with the following:

       ```sql
       SET @StringDocTime = convert(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 101);

       RAISERROR('%5d | %s | %7d | %#.6x | %6d | %7d', 10, 0,
                 @cnt, @StringDocTime, @LocId, @TicketId, @DocSeq, @DataLen)
                 WITH NOWAIT;
       ```

Comment: This fixed it. `SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647;`  Also, thanks for the other tips.  I'm a C# developer and got lazy with the commas since it's not enforced.  How can I set this at the server level so I don't need to do it within the job?  This way what I'm doing here won't be necessary since the normal replication would copy the images.

Comment: Should I consider converting the column to varbinary(max)?

Comment: @fourwhey There is no server-wide setting that I can find, and for some reason the default size is 4k. But you can set it in a job step as well as in the app code. Just call that statement first. You can set it anywhere so that you never need this correction script again. And yes, absolutely do use VARBINARY(MAX) instead of IMAGE. The TEXT / NTEXT / IMAGE datatypes were deprecated as of SQL Server 2005 ;-).

Comment: I found the offending stored procedure used to replicate the table in question and added SET TEXTSIZE to it. Replication is now copying the column rather than truncating it.  Now I just need to use the job I created to repair the old records.  Thank you again. I'd give you a vote+ if I had enough reputation. :(

Answer (score 0):

It's most probably the **max text repl size option**.
Can you run the following code on the server and let me know what are config_value & run_value currently set to?

```
exec sp_configure  'max text repl size (B)'
```

Comment: name: max text repl size (B), minimum: -1, maximum: 2147483647, config_value: 65536, run_value: 65536

Comment: @fourwhey `max text repl size (B)` is not relevant to your issue since it only "applies to transactional replication and Change Data Capture", and you stated that you created your own replication system. See  [max text repl size Server Configuration Option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179573.aspx) for more info.

Comment: @srutzky I thought as much but posted it anyway. Thank you for confirming it.